# BackgrounderWorker stopping in try-catch block

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

```
//static int var1, var2, var3;
//static List<string> list;

    public static void MyMethod(Object obj, int times)
    {
        List = doc1.Descendants("Order")
            .Select(d => d.Value)
            .ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = (from m in doc1.Elements("list").Elements("Order")
                                where m.Value == List[i]
                                select m);

                item.Remove();

                doc1.Save(path1);
                var1 = doc1.Root.Descendants("Order").Count();


                //DoSomethingHeavy with List[i]

                doc2.Element("list2").Add(new XElement("Order", List[i]));
                doc2.Save(path2);


                 var2= doc2.Root.Descendants("Order").Count();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                doc3.Element("list3").Add(new XElement("Order", List[i]));
                doc3.Save(path3);

                var3 = doc3.Root.Descendants("Order").Count();

            }
        }
    }
```

This is MyMethod in a public static class.
I'd like to making it running in a form under BackgroundWorker to be able to Pause and Resume execution.

I'm using this class:

```
public class BackgroundLoading
{
    public BackgroundWorker Bw;
    public delegate void RunFunction();
    public RunFunction thisFunction;



    public BackgroundLoading(RunFunction newFunction)
    {
        thisFunction = newFunction;
        Bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        Bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Bw_DoWork);
        Bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            //an error occured
            MessageBox.Show("an error occured: " + e.Error.Message);
        }
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            //an error occured
            MessageBox.Show("Job cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Job completed");
        }

    }

    void Bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" *");
    }

    void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (thisFunction != null)
            thisFunction();
    }
}

 //class to implement
```

then, in myForm:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundLoading bl = new BackgroundLoading(MyMethod());
        bl.Start();
    }
```

I'm really new to BackgroundWorker and probably i'm not using it the right way.
When StopExecution button is clicked, not all my doc (doc1,doc2,doc3) have been saved.
So how can I avoid from stopping in the try - catch block?

Comment: How do you handle *stop* execution request?

Comment: this way  private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

Comment: A Bgw is not well suited for Pause/Resume. Cancelling requires exposing a flag to `MyMethod()` .

Comment: Off topic: your use of `catch()` as part of the 'normal' logic looks very scary.

Comment: can you explain how to exposing a flag?

Comment: I only need my catch block to trace items not processed. Too poor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set [WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) to True to allow your BackgroundWorker to support cancellation.
2. Make your cancel button call the [CancelAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx) method.
3. Change your method by splitting into 2 methods. One should get an item number and the other will work item by item.
4. In your DoWork() method, put a check to see if there is a [cancellation pending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) and finish your process if there is.

   ```
     void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {

       //in your loop test every time Cancel flag       
       for (int i = 0; i < MyMethodGetItemcount(); i++)
       {
           MyMethod(i);//item by item
           if(yourbackgroundworker.CancellationPending)
           {
               e.Cancel = true;
               return;
           }
    }
   ```

Comment: Obvious...since you tell me! I will try. Thanks Hassan.